# Using a loop to improve jquery code

Tags: jquery, loops, getjson

How can I using a loop to improve this jquery code?

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetPainel", "Home")", {}, function(data) {
  var json = data;
  var PieData = [{
    value: data[0].value,
    color: data[0].color,
    highlight: data[0].highlight,
    label: data[0].label
  },{
    value: data[1].value,
    color: data[1].color,
    highlight: data[1].highlight,
    label: data[1].label
  }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't event need a loop**, you can just use `map()` to build a new array of objects from the one retrieved from your AJAX request:

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetPainel", "Home")", function(data) {
  var pieData = data.map(function(o) {
    return {
      value: o.value,
      color: o.color,
      highlight: o.highlight,
      label: o.label
    }
  }

  // work with pieData here...
});
```

** I mean *explicit* loop. I realise that `map()` loops internally.

Comment: elegant and efficient solution. Kudos.

Comment: It would be kinda silly to map over `data` if each element has just 4 keys and he's trying to copy it over...

Comment: @KarelG I agree, although I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt that they wouldn't be asking that question if it were possible to transpose an existing array

Comment: Very simple. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this

```
 $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetPainel", "Home")", {}, function (data) {
    var PieData=[];
    data.forEach(function(entry){
        PieData.push({
          value:entry.value,
          color:entry.color,
          highlight:entry.highlight,
          label:entry.label
       });
    });
```